# Dual of a statement involving adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

> Let $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ be a functor. The following
> conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $F$ is full and faithful and has a full and faithful left adjoint $G$.
> 2. $F$ has a left adjoint $G$ and the two canonical natural transformations $\eta:1_{\mathcal{D}}\Rightarrow F\circ G$ and
>    $\varepsilon:G\circ F\Rightarrow 1_{\mathcal{C}}$ are isomorphisms.
> 3. There exists a functor $G:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ such that $1_{\mathcal{D}}\cong F\circ G$ and $1_{\mathcal{C}}\cong G\circ
>     F$.
> 4. $F$ is full and faithful and for each $D\in\mathcal{D}$ there exists $C\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $D\cong F(C)$.
> 5. the dual condition of 1.
> 6. the dual condition of 2.

What are the duals of the statements 1 and 2? Are they the following?

1*. $F$ is full and faithful and has a full and faithful right adjoint $G$.

2*. $F$ has a right adjoint $G$ and the two canonical natural transformations $\eta:F\circ G\Rightarrow 1_{\mathcal{D}}$ and
$\varepsilon:1_{\mathcal{C}}\Rightarrow G\circ F$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, those are the duals. In an adjunction, if $G$ is left adjoint ot $G$, then $F$ is right adjoint to $G$. So maybe it would be more convinient to denote by $\eta$ the functor that has $1_C$ as domain and $\varepsilon$ the one that has $1_D$ as codomain, since you just have to switch $F$ and $G$ on conditions 1 and 2 (I'm not sure if this is more common than what you wrote).

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say "if $G$ is a left adjoint to $F$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A left adjoint for $F:C^{op}\to D^{op}$ is a functor $G:D^{op}\to C^{op}$ with a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{C^{op}}(Ga,b) \cong \hom_{D^{op}}(a,Fb) \text{ for all } a\in D, b\in C.
$$

Equivalently, this is a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{C}(b,Ga) \cong \hom_{D}(Fb,a) \text{ for all } a\in D, b\in C.
$$

This shows that in fact $G$ is a *right* adjoint for $F$, i.e. left and right adjoints are dual concepts.
This explains why 1* and 2* are correct.